# _curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal, Raspberry Pi

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi, ncurses, python-curses, terminfo

Every time I run this script on my Raspberry Pi:

```
import curses
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

motor1a = 7
motor1b = 11
motor1e = 22
motor2a = 13
motor2b = 16
motor2e = 15

GPIO.setup(motor1a,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(motor1b,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(motor1e,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(motor2a,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(motor2b,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(motor2e,GPIO.OUT)

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()  
curses.cbreak()
curses.halfdelay(3)
screen.keypad(True)

try:
    while True:   
        char = screen.getch()
        if char == ord('q'):
            break
        elif char == curses.KEY_UP:
            GPIO.output(motor1a,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(motor1b,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(motor1e,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(motor2a,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(motor2b,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(motor2e,GPIO.HIGH)
# except SOMEEXCEPTION is missing here, I am not sure why there is an exception in the first place
```

I get an error:

```
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal
```

How can I fix this?

I saw a post where it said to do the following:

> You must set environment variables `TERM` and `TERMINFO`, like this:
>
> `export TERM=linux ; export TERMINFO=/etc/terminfo`

But I'm not sure where to do that step.

Comment: This code cannot work - the indents are essential in Python. It is also missing a piece at the end (the closure of `try:`). I fixed it to hopefully something more python-like (`except` is still missing)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `curses`, you need to tell which terminal you are using so that the library can send correct commands. This is done by running the commands you provided in a shell, at the same place where you run your program

```
$ export TERM=linux
$ export TERMINFO=/etc/terminfo
$ python3 myprogram.py
```

(`$` is the prompt of the shell, you may have something else)

As I mentioned in my comment, your code will not run anyway, there is an `except` missing after the `try` (I am not sure what you need the `try` for, and you will need to understand this anyway in order to catch the right exception)